# Geometric Sequences in Manufacturing

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I came up with this problem:

The manufacturer of a company plans to produce and sell $8000$ units per year. Each year, 10% of the units become inoperative. 
So basically, I need a definition for this series, **recursive** or **explicit**, it does not matter.

I know that $A_1= 8000 + 0.9\cdot(8000)$, $A_2=8000 + 0.9\cdot(A_1)$, and so on.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=8,000$ and $q=0.9$ then you have

$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x\cdot q^k=x\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} q^k$

And the $S_{n-1}=x\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} q^k=S_n-X\cdot q^{n-1}$

Solve for $S_n$ to get the recurrence equation for $S_n$.

*Explicit formula for $S_n$*

$S_n=x\cdot \left[1+\color{blue}{q+q^2+...+q^{n-1}}\right] \quad (1)$

Now we multiply both sides by $q$.

$q\cdot x\cdot  S_n=x\cdot \left[ \color{blue}{q+q^2+q^3+...+q^{n-1}}+q^{n} \quad (2) \right]$

The blue marked terms are equal.

*$(1)-(2)$ gives*

$ S_n-q\cdot   S_n=1-q^n$

Now solve for $S_n$.