# Payment by instalments with changing instalment amount throughout payment

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

Task: 
You got an offer to buy a boat with a **present value of 10800€**.

The **deposit is 6000€** you have to pay **1200€ a year (as instalment**) for 3 years.

The rest of your debt is paid in **4 equal instalments** (which are also paid at the end of the year once a year, so the whole process takes 7 years).

Calculate the amount of the new instalment if the **annual interest rate is 8%**.

My Question: 
Is there any formular that could help me with this task, I tried everything I could for basically the whole day compound interest, normal interest, tables and nothing seems to work. 
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly we choose a reference date. All payments are discounted/compounded to this date. I choose $t=0$ (present).

The present value of $n$ equal yearly payments $r$, which a made at the end of the years is

$$PV=r\cdot \frac{(1+i)^n-1}{i\cdot (1+i)^n}, \ \text{where i is the interest rate}$$

Therefore the equation for your exercise is

$$10800=6000+1200\cdot \frac{(1+0.08)^3-1}{0.08\cdot (1+0.08)^3}+\underbrace{\underbrace{X\cdot \frac{(1+0.08)^4-1}{0.08\cdot (1+0.08)^4}}_{\text{value at t=3}}\cdot \frac1{(1+0.08)^3}}_{\text{present value at t=0}}$$

It remains to solve the equation for $X$. Feel free to ask if something is unclear.

Comment: Thanks! How did you come up with the first formular?

Comment: @BrunhildeLine This is a well known formula. The future value is $r\cdot \frac{(1+i)^n-1}{i\cdot (1+i)^n}\cdot (1+i)^n=r\cdot \frac{(1+i)^n-1}{i}=r\cdot \frac{(1+i)^n-1}{1+i-1}$. Let $q=1+i$. We get $r\cdot \frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$. This is the partial sum of a geometric series: $r\cdot (1+q+q^2+...+q^{n-2}+q^{n-1})=r\cdot \frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1555832/geometric-sequences-in-manufacturing/1555890#1555890) how the formula can be derived.